# Access an IVR Application menu choice manually from VXML server

Tags: ivr, vxml

How do I construct a URL to select a specific `<choice>` in  a `<menu>`?

I have a simple IVR Application which is Deployed on the CVP VXML Server. It starts with two `<audio>` elements, then a `<menu>` with two `<choice>`s, and finally `<disconnect>`.

When I call this application from a Cisco IP Phone, it works perfectly. But what I want to do is to call the application manually from my browser and get the VXML for every element.
I am able to make a connection to the server and it returns the first `<audio>` element VXML. I'm accessing it by going to:

```
Server:port/CVP/Server?application="APP_NAME"
```

This URL correctly returns the first `<audio>` element. When I want to access the next element I change the URL to:

```
Server:port/CVP/Server?application="APP_NAME" ? audio_file="next" method="post"
```

This URL correctly returns the next element. Then I enter the above URL again and it correctly returns the `<menu>` with both `'.

How do I construct the URL to select a specific `<choice>` on the menu as if I was navigating it on a phone call using DTMF, where I pressed 1 to have the call flow enter into one branch, and when I pressed 2 it entered into another branch?

Comment: List what the server returns for the vxml that has the menu options and I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the filled section of that vxml (that has the menu of 2 options). In the filled section, there would be some file that it is submitting to. Try to access that file in your URL (or try to replicate the path that the code is taking when one presses 2 - in your URL)

Answer (score 0):

Check the field name, that would be the parameter you would need to pass to the next page.